# How to hide child element using javascript

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have done javascript code for displaying main element if i click main element under all child elements should come but in my code is not working.

```js
$(function() {
  //alert("hello");
  $(".chlnode").parent().hide();
  $(".mainnode").click(function() {
    alert("mainnode is clicking");
    $(this).children('ul').show();
    $(this).siblings().find('ul').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>A</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>A1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>A3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>A2</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>A4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>A5</li>
      </ul>
      <ul></ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>B</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>B1</li>
    <li class='chlnode'>B2</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>B3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>B4</li>
      </ul>
      <ul></ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>C</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>C1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>C2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>C3</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <li class='chlnode'>C4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>C5</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>D</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>D1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>D4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>D3</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>D5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>D6</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <li class='chlnode'>D7</li>
        </ul>
        <ul></ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>E</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>E1</li>
  </ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>F</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>F1</li>
  </ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>G</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>J</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>J1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul></ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ul` is not a children here, but is `siblings`, try to make it as `children` , `$(this).children('ul').show();` there is no children in `mainnode`

Comment: I'd suggest you improve your HTML structure by placing the child `ul` within the parent `li`. This then becomes a trivial problem to solve. See @pedram's answer for an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the following code.

```
$(function() {
  //alert("hello");
  $(".chlnode").parent().hide();
  $(".mainnode").click(function() {
    alert("mainnode is clicking");
    $(".mainnode ~ ul").hide();
    $(this).next('ul').show();
  });
});
```

I've changed so `$(".mainnode ~ ul").hide();` will hide all ul before we show the one that corrospond to the clicked li.

Since your `li` has no children but only siblings, you can use `.next()` or `.siblings()`, like this `$(".mainnode ~ ul").hide();`

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  //alert("hello");
  $(".chlnode").parent().hide();
  $(".mainnode").click(function() {
    alert("mainnode is clicking");
    $(".mainnode ~ ul").hide();
    $(this).next('ul').show();
  });
});
```

```html
This is my html code i am generating php file.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>A</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>A1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>A3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>A2</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>A4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>A5</li>
      </ul>
      <ul></ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>B</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>B1</li>
    <li class='chlnode'>B2</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>B3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>B4</li>
      </ul>
      <ul></ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>C</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>C1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>C2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>C3</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <li class='chlnode'>C4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>C5</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>D</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>D1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>D4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>D3</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>D5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>D6</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <li class='chlnode'>D7</li>
        </ul>
        <ul></ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>E</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>E1</li>
  </ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>F</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>F1</li>
  </ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>G</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>J</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>J1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul></ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.it is working fine somehow .but problem with my php code while generating html how can i post the code here to check.

Comment: @Shivu I would advise you to make a new question regarding the php question,

Answer (score 1):

*You must fix your `html` code first then try something like this:*

```js
$(function() {
  $(".mainnode").click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').show();
    $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
li > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>A
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>A1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='mainnode'>B
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>B1</li>
      <li class='chlnode'>B2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The children always should be inside the parent:

```
<ul>
<li>
<ul><ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a much better solution overall. The only thing I'd suggest is to remove the `$(".chlnode").parent().hide();` line and put `li > ul { display: none; }` in CSS. This will avoid the FOUC on load

Comment: Yes, hiding in `css` much better @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

your html code should be like following

```
<ul>
  <li class='mainnode'>A
      <ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>A1</li>
        <ul>
          <li class='chlnode'>A3</li>
        </ul>
        <ul></ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>A2</li>
        <ul>
          <li class='chlnode'>A4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>A5</li>
          </ul>
          <ul></ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='mainnode'>B
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>B1</li>
    <li class='chlnode'>B2</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>B3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>B4</li>
      </ul>
      <ul></ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='mainnode'>C
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>C1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>C2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>C3</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <li class='chlnode'>C4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>C5</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='mainnode'>D
    <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>D1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>D4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>D3</li>
    <ul>
      <li class='chlnode'>D5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <li class='chlnode'>D6</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <li class='chlnode'>D7</li>
        </ul>
        <ul></ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</li>

  <li class='mainnode'>E
    <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>E1</li>
  </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='mainnode'>F
  <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>F1</li>
  </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='mainnode'>G
    <ul>
    <li class='chlnode'>J
        <ul>
          <li class='chlnode'>J1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```